# Index increase in inner function

Tags: matlab, function, input, global

I have a main Matlab code which I use in order to calculate ode.
The main code contains many lines but I will explain only the ones needed.

The code looks as following (short version):

```
global array
t0=0
x0=[5,5]
dt=0.01
tfinal=10

[tout,xout]=rk4('equation',t0,x0,dt,tfinal)   % the functions use the function 'equation' and calculates its values at every time from 0 to 20
```

Where 'equation' is another function from the following type:

```
global array 
Dydx = equation(t,x)
Dydx=[x(1)
            x(2)+array(j)]

            j=j+1
```

However, as can be seen, inside the function "equation" there is a variable j which I want to increase every t iteration of rk4.

Which means that while I calculate the ode for time t, the rk4 should use function 'equation' and increase the j by one and so on.

The problem I get is that if I try to make 'equation' gives output of j like [Dydx,j] =equation(t,x) I recieve an error because of rk4.

How can I increase j in the inner function while the outside functions also get the value?(tried global but it kept showing j as [] in the work space).

I have tried to make it global as following but it didnt work:

```
global array jcount
t0=0
x0=[5,5]
dt=0.01
tfinal=10
jcount = 1;

[tout,xout]=rk4('equation',t0,x0,dt,tfinal) 


global array jcount
Dydx = equation(t,x)
Dydx=[x(1)
            x(2)+array(jcount)]

            jcount=jcount+1
```

Thank you.
.

Comment: If I understand, you don't need to output `j` from `equation` to `rk`, you just need to give one more input from `rk` to `equation` that will indicate the number of iteration

Comment: And don't use `j` as a variable. Matlab know it as the root of -1, and it can cause unpredictable behavior or slowing in the computations.

Comment: But when I write [tout,xout]=rk4('equation',t0,x0,dt,tfina,j) it gives another input to rk4 which basically not passed to 'equation' since equation has its own input which has to be (t,x). And ye will change the name of the variable from j, thanks

Comment: I don't know completely how `rk` and `equation` looks like, so I can't be more specific. I wrote broadly from the couple of lines that you gave here. But stick to the concept- give `equation` another input that will represent the iteration number.

Comment: Why do you not calculate `j` as a function of `t`? That seems more reliable to me than assuming in which order the equation is called.

Comment: You can also define `j` as a `global` (but use a longer name in that case).